# How to import file with hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chainlink, oracles, import

I'm following the Alchemy tutorial to build an NFT Marketplace with hardhat. I want to import my smart contract which is an APIConsumer by Chainlink. I can't do it by path since I'm not allowed by hardhat. My idea is to be able to call a function of APIConsumer.sol from marketplace.sol.

How do I import it?
Thanks to all.

This is the link with the code of the marketplace: https://github.com/alchemyplatform/NFT-Marketplace-Tutorial

this is marketplace.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "/riskscoreAPI.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage{

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    
    //owner is the contract address that created the smart contract
    address payable owner;
    //The fee charged by the marketplace to be allowed to list an NFT
    uint256 listPrice = 0.01 ether;

    APIConsumer r;

    int256 risk=-1;
    ...
```

this is my APIConsumer.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {

    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    int256 private risk;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event RequestRisk(bytes32 indexed requestId, int256 risk);
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello [Giacomo](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/121287/giacomo-bertazzolo)

Chainlink has some [tutorials and examples](https://docs.chain.link/getting-started/other-tutorials) that can help you!

Check it out the [Hardhat Starter Kit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit)

Comment: They all use the path import